# Azure DevOps - Connect Test Case and Test Run in Report

Tags: testing, azure-devops

I am trying to create a report that shows me the connection of the test case and the latest test run, as well as connected defects.
At the moment I am only able to see the test run connected to the result in the test plan, but also the defect connection is missing.
How is it possible to set up a query that displays test case, test run status and connected defect status?
Best Regards

Comment: Can you share a screenshot to explain what `connected defects` specifically refer to? This will help us understand your question.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.